# Wordpress Site using removing a button on a slider (soliloquy)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, slider

I tried inputting CSS to "display:none" for the header button but it's not working.
I am looking at the slider.php file and [image]

http://9vq.ecf.myftpupload.com/
This is the site, I am trying to get rid of the "see below" button on the header slide image.

Comment: Post the custom css you used.  How did you target the button?  Use the Inspector (DevTools) to figure out which element needs `display:none` for the button to go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using chrome DevTools I could see that you need to target the following with your custom css (you may need to add `!important` if your css is being overridden)

```
.single-slide .btn-link {
    display: none;
}
```